# Dynamically adding complex HTML code within HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML code that describe a logical entity which contains 3 fields (2 drop downs and a number)

```
<div class="entityRowBorder">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>-- Select --</option>
                        <option>Option1</option>
                        <option>Option2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="number"  max="100" min="0" class="form-control" id="inputNumber1" placeholder="Number">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="inputExtra" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Extra</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>--Select Extra --</option>
                        <option>SQL Extra 1</option>
                        <option>SQL Extra 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Upon clicking an `Add` button (which appear after in the HTML)  I want to add dynamically this whole "entityRowBorder" `div` which contains those 3 fields.

What is the best way to do this addition?

Comment: where you want to add  `entityRowBorder` DIV contents?

Comment: Is entityRowBorder div is already generated or you want to generated it dynamically like :     $("<div>").html("test");

Comment: BTW are  you using jQuery?

Comment: What I tries so far with no success is having the whole div in several vars and then append it.

Comment: I want to add the entityRowBorder right after the last existing entityRowBorder and before the "Add Entity" bottun

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click event and make use of `.clone()` method:

```
$('#addbuttonid').on('click', function(){ // bind a click event
    var clone = $('.entityRowBorder:first').clone(); // get a clone of specific div
    $(this).before(clone); // push to the DOM just before the button
});
```

---

if you want to have a clone with existing data and events then you can pass `true` to the clone method:

```
var clone = $('.entityRowBorder:first').clone(true);
```

This lets you to have all the bound events and data with a new deep copy of a specific element.

Comment: Thanks very much Jai, it solve my problem and it's working fine

Comment: One thing I forgot to ask, how can I solve the problem of having non unique ID's and for="input1" text that created after the .before command?

Comment: @gorodesky when you execute `.before`  then you can do the Dom attribute change.